having problem while importing matplotlib moduels(font cache init error)
When I just try import matplotlib, then it doesn't show any error msg.
But when I try some modules or a library using matplotlib like seaborn, it shows an error msg.
If I write the import code below,
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
Soon it shows the msg below.
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
and after a few minutes, there comes the following error msg.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 1
----> 1 from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py:55
     53 from cycler import cycler  # noqa: F401
     54 import matplotlib
---> 55 import matplotlib.colorbar
     56 import matplotlib.image
     57 from matplotlib import _api

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/matplotlib/colorbar.py:19
     16 import numpy as np
     18 import matplotlib as mpl
---> 19 from matplotlib import _api, cbook, collections, cm, colors, contour, ticker
     20 import matplotlib.artist as martist
     21 import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/matplotlib/contour.py:15
     13 import matplotlib as mpl
     14 from matplotlib import _api, _docstring
---> 15 from matplotlib.backend_bases import MouseButton
     16 from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
     17 from matplotlib.path import Path
...
    272 except (OSError, subprocess.CalledProcessError, plistlib.InvalidFileException):
    273     return []
--> 274 return [Path(entry["path"]) for entry in d["_items"]]

KeyError: '_items'
Output is truncated. View as a scrollable element or open in a text editor. Adjust cell output settings...

I tried everything.
I set
import matplotlib as mpl
cache_dir = mpl.get_cachedir()
import shutil
shutil.rmtree(cache_dir)

!pip uninstall seaborn matplotlib -y
!pip install seaborn matplotlib

I made a virtual environment and re-installed every package needed at once.
python -m venv myenv
myenv\Scripts\activate
source myenv/bin/activate

pip install numpy pandas matplotlib torch pydicom

When I install them all, it shows everything has gone alright.
but it shows error msg when I import a module from matplotlib.
It all started when I tried to set up my new environment in my new M3-max MacBook Pro.
I didn't have any problems like this when I was using the Intel MacBook Air 2017.
now I can't do anything local environment.
Can you help me solve this problem?

I just rebooted and everything is going ok
